# SUBST: How to map to D: drive

Tags: cmd, drive, subst

```
subst x: myFolder
```

Works as expected.
Maps a new drive 'X' to the files of "myFolder".

```
subst d: myFolder
Invalid argument - D:
```

Why is that?

Does this mean, that it is not possible to map do D:\ ?

`subst (without parameters)` prints nothing (or only X: if mapped).
So D is not subst already.

Any clues about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear lord, I feel extremely stupid now.

The Laptop I am working on has mapped the **DVD drive** (which is deactivated but still mapped, hence you can not see it in the explorer) to D:\